# How to Point to Head so I can Rebase Again cleanly

Tags: git

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this:

▶ **git push origin log-in**

```
Counting objects: 110, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.
Writing objects: 100% (110/110), 12.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 110 (delta 64), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (64/64), completed with 25 local objects.
To https://github.com/xxxx
   4b13f34..b010a31  log-in -> log-in                                                                                                                                                                                                       1d § ✚  

branches/homepage  df9db35 ✗                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1d § ✚
```

▶ **git checkout log-in**

```
src/client/Api/UserApi.js: needs merge
src/client/actions/User/UserAsyncActions.js: needs merge
src/client/containers/LoginContainer.js: needs merge
src/client/reducers/UserReducer.js: needs merge
src/test/testImports.js: needs merge
src/test/unit/actions/user.async.action.spec.js: needs merge
src/test/unit/app.spec.js: needs merge
src/test/unit/usecases/authentication.feature.js: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

I just want to get back on track.  I want to get rid of this parallel changes in the tree and keep chugging along with rebase on top of head.[image]

Because when I started I had a nice rebase going on, all one line:[image]

**▶ git status**

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto bbea7dc
Last commands done (54 commands done):
   s a07cc17 added <Provider /> back into new reac-router v4 implementation to pesist store
   s 51fcda4 problem with call to API - getting 403
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
   s 55aaad5 added integration test script to package.json
   s d809245 fixed login test
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'log-in' on 'bbea7dc'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   package.json
        new file:   src/test/integration/api-integration-spec.js

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   src/client/Api/UserApi.js
        both modified:   src/client/actions/User/UserAsyncActions.js
        both modified:   src/client/containers/LoginContainer.js
        both modified:   src/client/reducers/UserReducer.js
        added by them:   src/test/testImports.js
        both modified:   src/test/unit/actions/user.async.action.spec.js
        both modified:   src/test/unit/app.spec.js
        both modified:   src/test/unit/usecases/authentication.feature.js
```

`You are currently rebasing branch 'log-in' on 'bbea7dc'.`

I just want to rebase on my main branch again which was log-in (not based on a specific commit but pointed to head

Comment: You are already in the middle of a rebase. You must either finish the one you have going right now, or abort the one you have going right now, before you can start a new one. I will note though that the phrase *not based on a specific commit but pointed to head* makes no sense in Git: everything is based on a specific commit, and HEAD just means "the current commit and/or current branch name" (when not in "detached HEAD" mode). Rebasing uses "detached HEAD" mode for the duration of the rebase, so you are in that mode right now, and will be until you finish or abort it.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to rebase but it keeps asking me to resolve merges.  ok

Comment: Rebase works by using `git cherry-pick` repeatedly, and *each* cherry-pick operation *is* a kind of merge. So until you either finish or abort your rebase you will likely keep hitting merge issues. (If you abort it, you can start over but you will presumably hit the same merge issues again, or you can run `git merge` instead, but you will presumably hit the same merge issues that way. Either way you will need to learn how to resolve merge conflicts...)